# PHP get arrays from one and add to the property of another

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. One is `taxonomies`:

```
Array
(
    [genres] => Array
        (
            [label] => Genres
            [value] => genres
        )

    [movie_tags] => Array
        (
            [label] => Movie Tags
            [value] => movie_tags
        )

    [portfolio_category] => Array
        (
            [label] => Portfolio Categories
            [value] => portfolio_category
        )

)
```

and `postTypes`:

```
Array
(
    [movies] => Array
        (
            [0] => genres
            [1] => movie_tags
        )

    [portfolio] => Array
        (
            [0] => portfolio_category
        )

)
```

Is it possible to combine the two arrays to get something like this?

```
Array
(
    [movies] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array ( [label] => Genres [value] => genres )
            [1] => Array ( [label] => Movie Tags [value] => movie_tags )
        )

    [portfolio] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array ( [label] => Portfolio Categories [value] => portfolio_category )
        )

)
```

I'm trying to add the `label` and `value` from `taxonomies` array into `postTypes` array but I'm not sure how to match the keys and combine the arrays. Is this possible with a foreach loop?

Comment: You are asking multiple questions / asking for multiole techniques and have shown no coding attempt -- please do not dump your requirements on Stack Overflow volunteers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `array_intersect_key()` will prevent any warnings from missing elements in your lookup array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YtQ1M))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($postTypes as $group => $taxKeys) {
    $result[$group] = array_values(
        array_intersect_key(
            $taxonomies,
            array_flip($taxKeys)
        )
    );
}
var_export($result);
```

Or if there is no risk of missing elements, a classic nesting of loops:
([Demo](https://3v4l.org/a4OPU))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($postTypes as $group => $taxKeys) {
    foreach ($taxKeys as $taxKey) {
        $result[$group][] = $taxonomies[$taxKey];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Or from PHP7.4, you can enjoy arrow functions to use custom functions without needing `use`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dhfIg))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($taxKeys) => array_map(
            fn($taxKey) => $taxonomies[$taxKey],
            $taxKeys
        ),
        $postTypes
    )
);
```

All of the above deliver the same output from the provided sample data.

Comment: I tried this but get `Warning: array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`

Comment: Then it appears that you have misrepresented your input data.  `array_flip((array)$taxKeys)` should do unless your really, really misrepresented your data.

Comment: I've added two more techniques that do the same thing so that you can choose the style that you like best.

Answer (score 1):

Since the values in `$postTypes` match the keys in `$taxonomies` it seems easiest to loop over the `$postTypes` array, and assuming these will only have one level of nesting, loop over the inner arrays.

If we loop over the inner arrays, the values of those will be equivalent to the keys in `$taxonomies`, that means that if we access `$taxonomies[$value]` we should get the array we want in our final result.

Thus, we could replace the values in place when looping over `$postTypes` as follows:

```
// Assigning the inner array by reference to update it in place.
foreach ($postTypes as &$innerArray) {
    foreach ($innerArray as $index => $value) {
        // Under the assumption that the values in postTypes
        // will always match the keys of taxonomies. Otherwise
        // you could add an additional check and logic.
        $innerArray[$index] = $taxonomies[$value];
    }
}

unset($innerArray);

echo '<pre>', print_r($postTypes, true), '</pre>';
```

The result we get:

```
(
    [movies] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Genres
                    [value] => genres
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Movie Tags
                    [value] => movie_tags
                )

        )

    [portfolio] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Portfolio Categories
                    [value] => portfolio_category
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: This works really well

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `array_map` function twice for external and internal arrays:

```
$res = array_map( // map external array
    function($el) use($taxonomies) {
        return array_map( // map internal array
            function($el) use ($taxonomies) {
                return $taxonomies[$el];
            },
            $el
        );
    },
    $postTypes
);
```

[PHP array_map online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=2a3c43e408675c9166b5a6eee2711aae&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)